Multiple queries fail to execute at once on Oracle with ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
I have a table which is created with the command below and exists in the DB:
create global temporary table tmp(id int) on commit delete rows;

I am a SQL server guy and need to convert lots of adhoc queries into Oracle. I need to do this simple thing in Oracle but I receive the error ORA-00933. I can run exactly the same thing in SQL Server without any issues.
insert into tmp values (100);
insert into tmp values (200);
insert into tmp values (300);
select table1.name from table1, tmp where table1.id = tmp.id;
commit;

The query originally was as follows in SQL Server:
create table #tmp (id int)
insert into #tmp values (100)
insert into #tmp values (200)
insert into #tmp values (300)
select table1.name from table1, #tmp t where table1.id = t.id
drop table #tmp

The prefered result is to have a list of names like:
name
_____
Apple
Poir
Cherry

Here is what I have as C# code:
DataTable myDataTable = new myDataTable();
Using(var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(query, connection))
{
    adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
}


table1? and really using comma joins?

@P.Salmon the names are not real. and for SQL you can replace the job with good looking inner join... on... clause

In Oracle each command must be a single SQL or PL/SQL statement. It is impossible to run multiple statements in a single command (this helps to prevent SQL injection attacks such as this XKCD).
You can either:

Run each statement individually.

Use an IDE that will run the statements as a script (the IDE will break up the script into individual statements and run them one-by-one).

Stop using temporary tables for small queries:
select name from table1 where id IN (100, 200, 300)

or:
WITH tmp (id) AS (
  SELECT 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 300 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t1.name FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN tmp t ON t1.id = t.id


Pass the data as a collection (provided your connection supports it):
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(:1))

Then pass in the array as a SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST type (or something similar).

Run a single PL/SQL block:
BEGIN
  insert into tmp values (100);
  insert into tmp values (200);
  insert into tmp values (300);
END;

or
insert into tmp (id) values (:id)

and bulk bind your values to the insert.
Then if you want to see the contents of the table use the SELECT outside of the block in a different command:
select t1.name from table1 t1 INNER JOIN tmp t ON t1.id = t.id

If you are using temporary tables that truncate on COMMIT then you will also need to turn auto-commit off.



Thanks for your answer, However, if you refer to my tmp table creation model, once you pass the commit, the tmp table will lose its values and the join won't return anything.

@HosseinPOURAKBAR Then don't COMMIT until after the SELECT.

And, please consider that I have put a simple fake query here, the real issue is more complicated and needs to be done exactly this way, so please do not suggest any solution that needs architecture change because it is not possible.

@HosseinPOURAKBAR None of the suggestions require any architecture changes (and I don't see why you would think that I have suggested any). What you are asking (run multiple statements in a single command) is impossible as Oracle forbids you from doing that but there are many ways to get the same effect with exactly the same architecture in an "Oracle" way; you just need to embrace that you are not using SQL Server any more and use the appropriate syntax/methodology for a new tool.

suppose that you have 10,000 inserts into tmp table, how can do it with union from dual ? Besides, my query is generated dynamically, I cannot hardcode anything neither I can use in(...), Also, my tmp table is used 100 times in different update/merge queries, so how can I define it each time that I need ? I am talking in big scale.

@HosseinPOURAKBAR If you need a temporary table then use a temporary table. See #5 - put the data in using one (or more) command(s) then use subsequent command(s) to perform the query(ies). If you don't want to generate lots of SQL statements then you can use an INSERT and bulk bind to to it to load the data.

After some more investigations, I came to know that I could use :
connection.BeginTransaction();

Then I can insert separately and fetch data with the same command used. The transaction will maintain my temporary values and once I close my connection, they will be dropped as expected.

Oracle uses implicit transaction management; you do not need to explicitly manage the transaction (but you may need to turn auto-commit off if you are using temporary tables).
